# What is the volume of a spherical ring that remains after driling a hole of radius b where b is less than the radius a where the ring has height x

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I would like to know how to find the volume of a spherical ring that
remains after driling a hole of radius b where b is less than the radius a 
where the ring has height x. Then, how could one demonstrate that the
volume of the spherical ring depends on the height x but independent of radius a?

Would this be possible with volume by shells, slicing or disks using one dimensional integration?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should consider subtracting the volume of the piece that was in the hole from the volume of the sphere.

Comment: See [Integrating volume of a sphere with a cylinder “drilled” out of it](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373203/integrating-volume-of-a-sphere-with-a-cylinder-drilled-out-of-it).

Comment: @dxiv, Thank you for the great answer.

Comment: @Bernard Masse, I thought your  answer was also great.